# Is there always a limit for upper Darboux sums as the norm of the partition approaches to zero?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that in all functions, whether they are integrable or not, the set of all upper Darbox sums has an infimum, and if this infimum (L(f)) is equal to the supremum of the set of all lower Darbox sums, we say that the function is Darboux-integrable in that interval. Considering that the Darbox integral and the Riemann integral are equivalent, we can conclude that the limit of the upper Riemann/Darbox sums is equal to L(f) when the norm of the partition approaches to zero. The question that has arisen for me is: Is there always a limit for upper Darboux sums as the norm of the partition approaches to zero or there may not be a limit but if there is, it's equal to the infimum of the set of all upper Darboux sums?

• It is assumed that the function we are talking about is bounded in the desired interval.

I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Denote by $P_2\succ P_1$, for two partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$ that $P_2$ is a refinement of $P_1$. Note that if $P_2\succ P_1$, then for the corresponding upper sum you have $U(f,P_2)\leq U(f,P_1)$. So, upper sums are decreasing (and thus have limit) along chains (totally ordered with respect to refinement). Note that those limits are also the infimum along the chain of partitions.

Comment: NDB What if p2 is not a refinement of p1. In that case how can we conclude this statement?

Comment: The thing is that for any two partitions $P_1,P_2$ (even if incomparable with respect to refinement) you can create a partition $P$ such that $P\succ P_1$ and $P\succ P_2$. For example $P=P_1\cup P_2$. And the upper sum for $P$ will be $\leq$ than the upper sums for $P_1$ and for $P_2$. So, the limit is the infimum.